# Concat 2 queries in mysql for inventory report

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 queries in my sql:

**Query 1**

```
SELECT
    product_id, 
    product_name, 
    SUM(case when type = "I" then quantity else 0 end) as import, 
    SUM(case when type = "O" then quantity else 0 end) as export, 
    SUM(case when type = "R" then quantity else 0 end) as refund, 
    (
        SUM(case when type = "R" then quantity else 0 end)
        - SUM(case when type = "O" then quantity else 0 end)
        +SUM(case when type = "I" then quantity else 0 end)
    ) as available

FROM
    `i1ntl_ldn_soft_inventory_detail`
WHERE 
    product_id = 2772 
    and date(refdate) < "2018-03-09" 
    and date(refdate)>= "2018-03-01"
GROUP by 
    product_id
ORDER BY 
    `import` DESC
```

The result is

[image]

**Query 2**

```
SELECT 
    product_id, 
    product_name, 
    (
        SUM(case when type = "R" then quantity else 0 end) 
        - SUM(case when type = "O" then quantity else 0 end)
        +SUM(case when type = "I" then quantity else 0 end)
    ) as available_start
FROM
    `i1ntl_ldn_soft_inventory_detail` 
WHERE 
    product_id = 2772 
    and date(refdate) < "2018-03-01"
GROUP by
    product_id
```

The result is:

[image]

Can I combine 2 those queries into 1 to get the result

```
Product_id, product_name, available_start, import, export, refund, available
```

Comment: I would suggest you see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation, and move the check on the `refdate` into the `CASE` expressions.  Then, you may use a single query.

```
SELECT
    product_id,
    product_name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'I' AND DATE(refdate) >= '2018-03-01' AND
             DATE(refdate) < '2018-03-09' THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS import,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'O' AND DATE(refdate) >= '2018-03-01' AND
             DATE(refdate) < '2018-03-09' THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS export,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'R' AND DATE(refdate) >= '2018-03-01' AND
             DATE(refdate) < '2018-03-09' THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS refund,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type IN ('R', 'I') AND DATE(refdate) >= '2018-03-01' AND
             DATE(refdate) < '2018-03-09' THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) -
        SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'O' AND DATE(refdate) >= '2018-03-01' AND
                 DATE(refdate) < '2018-03-09' THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS available,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type IN ('R', 'I') AND DATE(refdate) < '2018-03-01'
             THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) -
        SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'O' AND DATE(refdate) < '2018-03-01'
                 THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS available_start
FROM i1ntl_ldn_soft_inventory_detail
WHERE product_id = 2772
GROUP by product_id
ORDER BY import DESC
```

Comment: I think you forgot the condition `date(refdate)>= "2018-03-01"` in the case  for query one.

Comment: @Susang I edited my answer, but I don't recall seeing a date range anywhere in the OP before the latest edit.